# Docker rm blocks concurrent runs

Tags: docker

I want to run a lot of docker containers in foreground mode like `docker run johndoe/example doSomething`.

I don't want to waste disk space on exited containers, so I have to remove them. But it takes about 9 seconds to remove an exited container, so I should remove the container after the command execution.

That's why I have two concurrent processes: one runs containers, the other removes them.
The problem is that `docker rm` appears to be blocking - it doesn't run while removing.

Here is a minimal working example. Following command runs a docker container every second, then print current date to the console:

```
while true; do docker run ubuntu ls > /dev/null; sleep 1; date; done
```

And the output is like:

```
Tue Sep 30 14:25:18 MSK 2014
Tue Sep 30 14:25:20 MSK 2014
Tue Sep 30 14:25:22 MSK 2014
Tue Sep 30 14:25:24 MSK 2014
```

But when I run `docker rm some_id` in a separate console, then I see that the time span increases like:

```
Tue Sep 30 14:26:53 MSK 2014
Tue Sep 30 14:26:55 MSK 2014
Tue Sep 30 14:27:03 MSK 2014
Tue Sep 30 14:27:10 MSK 2014
```

Am I getting something wrong? Why is it so? How can I deal with it?

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution to this issue?

Comment: @vote539 as far as I remember, we added a cron job to remove containers making the server unavailable for some time. So, I don't know how to deal with it in a better way

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing multiple containers in one rm command? This may reduce the number of hiccups. Perhaps you could do that once a day at a time where a hiccup is not important to you?

Also, have you measured how much disk space gets consumed, it may not matter for a long time thanks to the nature of the overlay filesystems. Of course this depends on what your doSomething actually does...

Answer (score 0):

As in the docker-user mailing list - can you please post the output from

`docker version ; docker info`

as this may well be storage driver and setup specific

(though perhaps you just have so many containers or images that your system is going to take time to process them.